# Create dynamic list for expansion tile from Firestore data

Tags: list, flutter, dynamic, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to create a dynamic expansionTile, which receives as input data from Cloud Firestore.

Currently I download the data as array from Firebase and sort it into 3 different arrays ("Makeup", "Hair", Men's").
[Data structure Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L47LQ.png)

But I have to create a list according to the following scheme:

[How the List should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQyNn.png)

How can I merge the three lists to one such list?

[image]

Comment: When you say dynamic ExpansionTile, do you mean you want an ExpansionTile for each Entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the array and sort the data as List for each category.
Say you got 3 List ie. makeup, hair, and men's. Now you can use the spread operator to make the final List

Example

```
final List<Entry> data = [
  Entry(
    'Makeup',
     ...makeup
  ),
  Entry(
    'Hair',
     ...hair
  ),
  Entry(
    'Men`s',
     ...mens
  ),
]
```

Comment: However, the data structure does not consist of 3 arrays, but 3 json structures. I added another picture to my question... Could you help?